# notcertified: Upload failed: The PDF file has not been certified by PDF eXpress; created by TeX instead

Tags: pdf, ieee-style

I'm uploading the final version on edas, but the IEEE pdf express notices the error that notcertified: Upload failed: The PDF file has not been certified by PDF eXpress; created by TeX instead.
How could I modify the latex file to meet the requirements?

Comment: ask ieee for instructions.

Comment: I'm not fully sure but I think that the idea is to upload the source files (with extension `.tex` and `.bib` etc) and then the system compiles and verifies it, i.e., you should not upload an already compiled pdf - maybe that is the issue here?

Comment: Please tell us what you uploaded. The *.tex? The *.pdf? Images? *zip?

Answer (score 1):

Upload the paper to IEEE PDF Express: https://ieee-pdf-express.org/

The website will generate a verified version of your PDF that you can now upload to IEEE.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the conference webpage, and under "Author", you will find "instructions for final paper upload" if you are submitting to the same conference as me :). Otherwise, go through the paper acceptance email sent by the organizer to you, there should be instructions on the final upload.